# Is there a way to run tests without doing a full build in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there a way to provide a small test window without performing a complete build in Xcode? I know that eclipse gives you a small preview window at the bottom of the IDE but I can not figure it out for Xcode. I am mainly looking to test certain conditions and outputs that may not always print a value to the screen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your testable code into a framework that is accompanied by its own unit test bundle. Now testing involves just clicking the little run button next to a unit test. You can run a single test method or a whole suite, depending on your needs. When you run a test, the  entire app does not need to be built — just the framework; and the app itself never runs and the Simulator never opens. And the results appear in the little Xcode Console pane at the bottom of the project window (and are preserved also in the Report navigator).

This is an excellent way to organize your app structure. I routinely use this kind of architecture.

Comment: Is there any article that you could provide to follow that procedure?. Regards